# Ошибка подключение стилей CSS

Tags: html, css

Впервые пишу вёрстку через  PyCharm. Столкнулся с проблемой, что html не хочет подключать стили CSS (просто не видит файл). Если прописывать слили в HTML файле, то они работают. Помогите разобратся, в чём тут дело.

[image]

Если же я удаляю файл, то в подсказках он предлагает его создать, но даже так не будет его видеть

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в том что нужно сперва выходить потом показать путь

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">`

Comment: Попробовал, но ничего не изменилось. Я пытался прописывать и абсолютный путь, и Toolbox URL, но стили никак не применяются